# Wordpress users table missing indexes

Tags: database, permissions

I had someone on fiverr design a wordpress website for me awhile back. They sent me the database when they were done and I imported it on my server and set everything up.

What I've since realized is something is funky with the database.

I'm able to add plugins without issues, I've edited some pages here and there, but if I try to create a new post, page, etc I get a message that I'm "Currently editing the page that shows your latest posts."

Additionally, my users table shows zero indexes when I view the structure so in phpMyAdmin I get a warning message "Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available." Yet, if I try to create a primary index on the ID field I get an error message "Duplicate entry '0' for key `PRIMARY`"

I'm stumped. Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Should I just export the site, create a new wordpress installation, and then import everything? I'm just afraid of inadvertently importing whatever is causing the issue.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the auto increment handling is not setup correctly.

Go into phpMyAdmin and make sure that the `PRIMARY KEY` is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`

You can also run this SQL command:
`ALTER TABLE wp_users AUTO_INCREMENT = 1`

The `1` above you need to make sure the auto increment value is set to the highest number +1 in that table under `id`, see here for specifics on that:
[Is it possible to fix/repair all Index, Primary Key, Unique (and all other) structure of a Wordpress MS Database](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/329162/is-it-possible-to-fix-repair-all-index-primary-key-unique-and-all-other-stru/329166#329166)

You could also try starting from a fresh install and on import make sure you set it to update, as well as making sure when the db was exported by that person, under `Structure` that they select `Add AUTO_INCREMENT values` before exporting

https://cfdbplugin.com/?page_id=520

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database structure and constraints match the WordPress standard database description as in the screenshot.
For details refer to https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description
[image]