# Can't add users in admin after copying database

Tags: users, admin

This is a really strange issue. I'm testing a large production Woocommerce site with a 2 gig database. The production site needs updates to Woocommerce and plugins, so I want to test on staging. I can add users on the production site, and Woocommerce subscriptions work.

I copy the database to a testing subdomain using mysqldump and change all URLs in the database using wp-cli. Everything on the staging site works - sandbox checkout of current users, etc - except adding users via New User in admin. This also means Woocommerce subscriptions don't work, as that process adds a user as part of the checkout. (Yes, Woocommerce subscriptions are correctly enabled as a sandbox for testing on staging.)

When I try adding a new user in admin, the page loads for a few seconds and I see the green flagged WP alert that the user has been added. But when I search for the user in admin and in PHPMyAdmin, the user hasn't been added. The site admin gets an email that a user has been added, but the username and email are blank.

There are no errors in debug, no errors when using a query monitor, no errors in the general server php error log or in the MySQL or slow query log.

On staging, I've tried manually replacing all WP core files/folders, deactivating all plugins and using the 2019 theme.

I've raised max_input_vars and post_max_size in PHP7.2.

Server is Maria 10.2. I've repaired all database tables.

I can add users using a query directly in PHPMyAdmin.

Trying to add a user with wp-cli
`wp user create username user@yahoo.com --role=subscriber`
results in an "Error: Unknown error creating new user"

When I create a *new* database on staging and install WP as a "new" site with the same WP files/folders and plugins, I can add new users in admin. But as soon as I go back to the working database copied from production, I can't add users.

Comment: Can you add users programmatically either via CLI or `wp_create_user`?

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting; with wp-cli I get "Error: Unknown error creating new user." Does wp-cli use wp_create_user?

Comment: And if I run create user again with the same creds, I get a duplicate entry database error for the wp_users table, but searching the database doesn't show the user name or email. wp-cli debug doesn't show any fatal errors.

Comment: Are you connecting to the correct database?

Comment: I'm in public_html of the WP site using SSH. debug shows the correct database being called.

Comment: Yes, but are the database credentials in your wp-config.php file pointing to the correct database?

Comment: Yes, and wp-cli debug shows the correct ABSPATH to the install

Comment: I'm getting the duplicate entry error with username/email I know doesn't exist, so I think that error is spurious.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90581/discussion-between-mikengarrett-and-bluedogranch).

Comment: Thanks, can't chat right now; I've got a bunch of things going on. But I found that the duplicate entry error has to do with the user ID; something is causing WP or wp-cli to try and use an existing user ID, not a new ID incremented past the highest existing ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key turned out to be that the `wp_users` table lost its `AUTO_INCREMENT` setting when it was imported, for unknown reasons; the server may have timed out, etc.

I found this out from the wp-cli error in the debug log that said `"WordPress database error Duplicate entry '1000075' for key 'PRIMARY' for query INSERT INTO 'wp_users'`and in PHPMyAdmin, I could see that the ID `1000075` was already assigned to a user.

Even though the `wp_users` table showed `AUTO_INCREMENT`set in PHPMyAdmin, I ran this query to set it anyway:

`ALTER TABLE pw_users AUTO_INCREMENT = last-ID-plus-1`

where `last-ID-plus-1` is the highest ID that exists in `wp_users`, plus 1, i.e. in my case was

`ALTER TABLE pw_users AUTO_INCREMENT = 1003000`

After setting `AUTO_INCREMENT`, I can add users.

Reference: @N00b's answer for [Wordpress Database lost auto increment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/225641/wordpress-database-lost-auto-increment/311093#311093)